# I wonder connection between spring form tag & controller @RequestMapping() method

Tags: spring, annotations

1. This jsp file 'selectDetail.jsp' for client inputs their information 
   and clicks 'update' button to 'update.do'

```html
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>    
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title><spring:message code="member.detail.title"  arguments="${member.id}"/></title>
    </head>
    <body>
     아이디 : ${member.id}<br>
     비밀번호 : ${member.passwd }<br>
     이름 : ${member.name }<br>
     날짜 : ${member.reg_date }<br>
     <a href="list.do">목록보기</a> | 
     <a href="update.do?id=${member.id }">update</a> | 
     <a href="delete.do?id=${member.id }">삭제</a> | 
    </body>
    </html>
```

2. 'UpdateController.java' is get 'update.do' command by '@RequestMapping'.
   first, 'updateForm() is worked. b/c of method is get. go to 'updateForm.jsp'

```html
package dr.mini.controller;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import dr.mini.dao.MemberDao;
import dr.mini.domain.MemberCommand;
import dr.mini.validator.MemberValidator;

@Controller
public class UpdateController {
 private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass()); 
 
 @Autowired
 private MemberDao memberDao;

 public void setMemberDao(MemberDao memberDao) {
  this.memberDao = memberDao;
  System.out.println("UpdateController의 setMemberDao()호출");
 }
 
 //1) Get방식: value(요청명령어), method(방식종류)
 @RequestMapping(value="/update.do", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
 public ModelAndView updateForm(@RequestParam("id") String id){
  MemberCommand memberCommand = memberDao.getMember(id);
  System.out.println("1updateForm()");
return new ModelAndView("updateForm", "memberCommand", memberCommand);
  
 }

 
 //2) Post방식
 @RequestMapping(value="/update.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public String submit(MemberCommand memberCommand, BindingResult result){
  
  if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
   log.debug("3memberCommand="+memberCommand);
  }
  MemberValidator mv = new MemberValidator(); 
  System.out.println("validate 실행 전 ");
  mv.validate(memberCommand, result);
  System.out.println("validate 실행 후 ");
  
  
  if(result.hasErrors()){ 
   System.out.println("updateForm()으로 페이지 이동");
   return "updateForm"; 
  }
  
  memberDao.updateMember(memberCommand); 
  
  return "redirect:/list.do";  
 }
}
```

3. 'updateForm.jsp' outputs memberCommand information. client changes his infomation. He clicks '보내기' button. then go for 'UpdateController.java' again to call 'submit()'

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>      
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><spring:message code="member.update.title"/></title>
</head>
<body>

 <h2>레코드 수정</h2>

 <form:form commandName="memberCommand">
 <form:errors element="div"/>
  아이디 : ${memberCommand.id}<br>
  비밀번호 : <form:password path="passwd" showPassword="false"/><font color="red"><form:errors path="passwd"/></font><br>
  이름 : <form:input path="name"/><font color="red"><form:errors path="name"/></font> <br>
   
  <input type="submit" value="보내기">
  
 </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

everyone, 
I don't know how to call submit(). when client clicked '보내기' button with no 'update.do' path. Where is it to add this path.

Comment: typing the code. I contain java format not using snippet. what kind of editor's function is it?